# Display only 1 image out of 3 images, function use?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html

Having difficulty with the function showResults () which generates the table. I would like to display 1 image from a choice of 3 images depending on if the key:value data has a 1 between "HasPDF", "HasMobile"  or "apponly". SO I tried to use an if-then-else statement to sift through the 3 possibilities. 
Any advise? thank you. been going round and round..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table {
    margin: 3px;
}
table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table th, table td {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

</style>
<script>

var arr = [

    {
      "Inn_ID": "2292522",
      "Event_Name": "Jaguars ",
      "Event_Date": "2017-11-19 00:00:00",
      "ticket_total": "76.0",
      "HasPDF": "1",
      "HasMobile": "0",
      "apponly": "0"
    },
    {
      "Inn_ID": "2292523",
      "Event_Name": "Pelicans",
      "Event_Date": "2018-01-16 00:00:00",
      "ticket_total": "50.0",
      "HasPDF": "0",
      "HasMobile": "1",
      "apponly": "0"
    },
    {
      "Inn_ID": "2292524",
      "Event_Name": "Owls",
      "Event_Date": "2018-01-16 00:00:00",
      "ticket_total": "60.0",
      "HasPDF": "0",
      "HasMobile": "0",
      "apponly": "1"
    }

];

$(function() {
    $('#headings th').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var asc = (!$(this).attr('asc')); // switch the order, true if not set

        // set asc="asc" when sorted in ascending order
        $('#headings th').each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('asc');
        });
        if (asc) $(this).attr('asc', 'asc');

        sortResults(id, asc);
    });

    showResults();
});

function sortResults(prop, asc) {
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
    });
    showResults();
}

function image(thisImg) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = thisImg;
    document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(img);
}

function showResults () {
    var html = '';
    for (var e in arr) {
        html += '<tr>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].Event_Date+'</td>'
            +'<td><a href="https://www.thexx.com/orders/view-invoice/'+arr[e].Inn_ID+'" target="_blank">'+arr[e].Inn_ID+' </a></td>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].ticket_total+'</td>'
            +'<td>'+if (arr[e].HasPDF == "1") {
                       image('pdf.png');
                        } else if (arr[e].HasMobile == "1"){
                        image('mobile.jpeg');
                        } else {image('link.png');} 
                        +'<div id="imageDiv" style="width=20"></div></td>'
        +'</tr>';
    }
    $('#results').html(html);
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

Click on the table headings to sort the results.
<table>
    <thead id="headings">
        <tr>
            <th id="Event_Date">Event Date</th>
            <th id="Inn_ID">Inn ID</th>
            <th id="ticket_total">Amount</th>
            <th id="order">Order Type</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results">
        <!-- this will be auto-populated -->
    </tbody>
</table>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a rewritten your function since there were some caveats which could cause your code to crash. I will explain them later, but first the code:

```
function showResults(arr) {
  var html = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var image = arr[i].hasPDF ? 'pdf.png' : (arr[i].hasMobile ? 'mobile.jpeg' : 'link.png');

    html += '<tr>';
    html +=   '<td>' + arr[i].Event_Date + '</td>';
    html +=   '<td>';
    html +=     '<a href="https://www.aceticket.com/orders/view-invoice/' + arr[i].Invoice_ID + '" target="_blank">';
    html +=       arr[i].Invoice_ID;
    html +=     '</a>';
    html *=   '</td>';
    html +=   '<td>';
    html +=     arr[i].ticket_total;
    html +=   '</td>';
    html +=   '<td>';
    html +=     '<div id="imageDiv" style="width=20">';
    html +=       '<img src="' + image + '" />';
    html +=     '</div>';
    html +=   '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

  }

  $('#results').html(html);
}
```

First thing I did was structuring the `HTML` for better readability, just like you would with plain `HTML`. Luckily `JavaScript` is very "white-space-friendly" which makes this possible.

Second thing I did was ditching the `image()` `function`. This `function` was mixing `document` methods with `HTML` string creation. That was the cause your code was not running as expected.

It was (knid of) a race condition. Let me explain it like this:

1. You create a String containing `HTML`markup.
2. In the midst of creating it you tried to append the image tag from the `image()` function to a `div` (also this `div` was only existent inside the string and even after the `image()` function was called.)
3. with the `html()` function from `jQuery` you finally create the `DOM` from the markup you created inside the string.

Your approach was not entirely false, but had some downsides to it.
After the third step you could have accessed the DOM to `append()` something to it.

An alternative to the `image()` function was simply to create an `img` tag inside your string as well and pass it a variable which holds the image filename. I did this with a nested `ternary operator` to save some space.

I hope you like my solution to your problem and if I can be of any help please comment! ;)

Comment: OK -- thank you. I will try to place this within the main code.

Comment: yes - I like the ternary operator. I was somehow going to use that ternary operator but got lost in the - well there it is/ was.

Comment: Also since the array is within the <script> tag , arr doesn't need to be passed into the showresults() function ?

Comment: No, you don't need to pass it in, but it is safer to do so, especially, when you have more than this inside your script.

Answer (score 0):

Use this search and image function
here is running example
https://plnkr.co/edit/3Sx3wnzFDFj4wKrv06qS?p=preview

```
function showResults () {
    var html = '';
    for(var e =0; e< arr.length; e++)
      {
        var x=""

        html += '<tr>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].Event_Date+'</td>'
            +'<td><a href="https://www.aceticket.com/orders/view-invoice/'+arr[e].Invoice_ID+'" target="_blank">'+arr[e].Invoice_ID+' </a></td>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].ticket_total+'</td>'
            +'<td><div id="imageDiv'+e +'" style="width=20"></div></td>'
        +'</tr>';
    }
    $('#results').html(html);
     for(var e =0; e< arr.length; e++)
     {
        if(arr[e].HasPDF == "1")
        {
          x='pdf.png';
         } 
         else if (arr[e].HasMobile == "1")
         {
                       x='mobile.jpeg';
        } 
        else
        {
          x='link.png';

        } 
         image(x ,e);
     }
}

function image(thisImg,e) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = thisImg;
    document.getElementById('imageDiv'+e).appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: maybe you should explain a bit what went wrong with his code. He woint learn a thing from just copy/paste.

Comment: sure, thanks. you already explain the thing, it will help him lot

Answer (score 0):

Your image function does not return anything and you are appending to a div (#imageDiv) that does not currently exist on the DOM. You are also assigning the same id (#imageDiv) to multiple divs.

you would want to try this :

```
 function image(thisImg) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = thisImg;
    return img;
}
```

and

```
 function showResults () {
   var html = '';
   for (var e in arr) {
    html += '<tr>'
        +'<td>'+arr[e].Event_Date+'</td>'
        +'<td><a href="https://www.aceticket.com/orders/view-invoice/'+arr[e].Invoice_ID+'" target="_blank">'+arr[e].Invoice_ID+' </a></td>'
        +'<td>'+arr[e].ticket_total+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+if (arr[e].HasPDF == "1") {
                   '<div id="imageDiv" style="width=20">'+ image('pdf.png');+'</div></td>'
                  } else if (arr[e].HasMobile == "1"){
                   '<div id="imageDiv" style="width=20">'+ image('mobile.jpeg');+'</div></td>'
                  } else {
                    '<div id="imageDiv" style="width=20">'+ image('mobile.jpeg');+'</div></td>'
                  } 
        +'</tr>';
       }
       $('#results').html(html);
  }
```

Comment: true it is not returning anything, but why should a function even exist to create that image tag? It is not needed at all.

Comment: I thought it was a great thing to have had that function outside the already cluttered showResults function. It makes the code much more readable.

http://www.codereadability.com/are-one-line-functions-a-good-idea/

Comment: But the function itself is totally useless ... he can get the result he is looking for with much less code, which makes the code more readable as well! ;)

Comment: I like my version because I use less code but I got lost for the last column.  thank you for this explanation